# how to get the size of file/folder being downloaded in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an android app and using phonegap 2.6.0 What I want to do is to download a file/folder. I want the size of file portion that is being downloaded.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out FileTransfer.onprogress

```
fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
      loadingStatus.setPercentage(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total);
    } else {
      loadingStatus.increment();
    }
};
fileTransfer.download(...); // or fileTransfer.upload(...);
```

I think what you are looking for is progressEvent.total

Comment: var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                            var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100;
}
};
This is what I was trying but somehow I am getting the loaded size twice as that of the total size...Thanks in advance @whodee

Comment: not sure what you are doing, some of your code would be helpful to see.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment. Its working fine but what my actual need is to reflect this value continuously in a progress bar. I have tried it using jquery but it didn't work.Could please guide me thorough this?

Comment: what have you tried?  can you show your code and we can then see what wasn't working.

Comment: under the function for downloading a file from the url which i get from the server, I have written code for catching the size of file being downloaded like:
var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        perc = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
    }

Comment: Please check the code on the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774061/adding-progress-bar-for-file-being-downloaded-using-phonegap-and-jquery

Comment: I posted an answer to that question